# issue SLF4J + OWL API Scala Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, owl

I have a problem with slf4j while programming in scala with Eclipse (Maven project): 
I try to import an ontology with owl API. 
Particularly, I try to use the command `loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument` to load an owl file and I get the following error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

I've already tried to delete useless dependencies and reload project. But it seems that dependencies are installed again everytime I run the code.
Does anyone has encountered this issue ?

Comment: This is not an error but a warning? And how do you "delete" dependencies? The only way in Maven is to **exclude** them. And this is a common problem quite often asked here, thus a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. message printed on console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671133/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings-message-printed-on-console)

Comment: I agree this is a duplicate of the other question. You need to use an exclusion or remove the extra dependencies that are bringing in multiple bindings. OWLAPI by default does not import any bindings, so the source of the issue is likely in other dependencies. In Eclipse you can use the pom editor to explore the dependency hierarchy.

Comment: Or on the command line something like `mvn dependency:tree | grep -n20 slf4j`

Comment: @pp3456 It would be good if you answer to our comments. Even if you could solve the problem, it's a good practice to post the answer. That's how Stackoverflow works, otherwise this platform would be useless.